How to Improve Wireshark Capture Speed for USB Packets to Match Real-Time Data Transfer Rate?
I'm currently facing an issue with Wireshark where it cannot keep up with the real-time USB data transfer rate in my use case. This results in Wireshark only capturing a portion of the USB packets, which significantly hampers my ability to continue with my work.

Filtered Capture: I've attempted to use capture filters to reduce the amount of data being processed. For example:

 usb.data.len == 64

However, It can't work.

Display Filters: Post-capture, I'm using display filters to isolate the relevant packets, but this doesn't solve the issue of packets being missed during capture.

Problem:
Wireshark's capture speed is too slow to match the actual USB data transfer speed. This results in significant packet loss during capture.
What I'm Looking For:
What can I do to optimize Wireshark to capture USB data packets at a speed that matches the real-time data transfer rate? Are there specific techniques, settings, filters, or even alternative tools that can help with this?
